# Некоректная работа CSS Flexbox

Tags: css, css3, flexbox

Пару месяцев назад я без проблем реализовал то, что сегодня заставило провозиться больше часа, но все равно сейчас не понимаю, почему все работает как то "не так" как ожидается, ведь благодаря прекрасным флексбоксам все должно работать без всяких танцев с бубнами (о которых чуть дальше)

итак, первый код, который сегодня решил написать с нуля:

```css
.block3-parts {
  font-family: "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
 background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.block3-parts div {
 flex: 50%;
}

.block3-parts img {
 flex: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block3-parts">
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis quidem quasi illo consectetur velit temporibus, eum eveniet necessitatibus laborum culpa quam nobis iste sed, maxime perspiciatis ad reiciendis doloremque reprehenderit.</h4>
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/443446/pexels-photo-443446.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" alt="">
    </div>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o8w9caqe/)**

старый код, который работает как надо и пришлось вернуться к нему, чтобы все таки узнать, почему первый код не работает:

```css
.anim-blocks {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 align-items: center;
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
          border-radius: 15px;
          padding: 5%;
}

.anim-blocks .flex-photo{
 flex: 50%;
}

.anim-blocks h4 {
 flex: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="anim-blocks" >
  <h4 class="fadeInLeft wow animated">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi ipsa ex velit consequatur quod quis facilis repellendus, rerum, nesciunt consectetur repellat delectus dolorum dicta qui atque odit nam, provident laborum.
   </h4>
   <div class="flex-photo"><img style="max-width: 100%; height:auto;" src="https://onthehub.com/evolution-of-windows/img/windows-7/computer.png"  alt="" >
  </div>
 </div>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xyw72ndk/)**

они немного разные, но суть та же, - разделить окно на две части (ровно по половине), с одной стороны текст, с другой фото и чтобы при уменьшении размера окна все было адаптивно

и тут (во втором примере) кстати как раз танцы, о которых я писал, - это то, что нужно прописывать самой фотографии `max-width: 100%;` зачем? даже не понимаю как я раньше к этому пришел, наверное методом тыка, но сейчас хочу понять что к чему и почему без этого параметра ничего не работает как надо, обьясните пожалуйста

Собственно вопрос - почему фото не уменьшается при уменьшении размера окна, ведь и ему и тексту установлено по 50%? это же и должны делать флексбоксы или я чего то не понимаю?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.block3-parts {
  font-family: "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
 background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.block3-parts div {
 flex: 50%;
}

.block3-parts img {
 flex: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block3-parts">
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis quidem quasi illo consectetur velit temporibus, eum eveniet necessitatibus laborum culpa quam nobis iste sed, maxime perspiciatis ad reiciendis doloremque reprehenderit.</h4>
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/443446/pexels-photo-443446.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" alt="">
    </div>
```

*.block3-parts div а где этот див в коде? у тебя ж только заголовок и имж а flex-basis который установлен через flex указывает элементу что он НЕ СЖИМАЕТСЯ менее 50%, но растягивается по своей ширине. Перечитай свойства flex-ов
*

Comment: как где? вон как конь... чет ничего не понял из вашего поста